# To whom should god pray?

Tags: gods, belief

Once I heared somewhere (I am not sure where, may be it was on Christmas Midnight Mass - but it does not matter) one very strange short tale - that man entered to church, that was empty excepting god that prayed to people. I like that.

So, if a world you are building has a God, to whom should that god pray?

Comment: Which god? This is very broad as it would depend heavily on the specific mythology you want to use.

Comment: I don't quite understand the story or how the question is relevant to worldbuilding. Is it something about a human representation of god and wether this human body should pray to a god?

Comment: God likes it when people pray to him - that's what I've been told when I was a child. So he just prays to himself. It's very common for animals and humans that they do some activities that give them great pleasure to themselves, alone, even though it is intended to be done differently and in combination with other animals. Since God has made man to his image in Christianity, it is logical to assume that the Christian god performs similar acts

Comment: Putting a note that it "is in a world that you are building" does **not** make this on topic. _The question_ needs a world, _the question_ needs to describe that world for us, _the question_ needs to describe the god in question, and, based on that information, _maybe_ we can give an answer. Though, I would actually say that this question is still probably too story-based and too broad. _Worldbuilding.SE is not an idea generation engine._

Comment: AD&D's Forgotten Realms setting had a novel series in which it turns out there was an over-god above the gods. Ao was his name. He cast the gods out... interesting series.

Answer (score 2):

I once played Black & White. In the game you are a god and you power depends on people praying to you. So, you could pray to the humanity as an entity to accept you for what you are and give you more power.

For us, individuals, it is hard to understand if there is some sort of collective will of the people, but our society already behaves as a life form. Unfortunately, that life form doesn't seem to be self aware. So, I imagine that god praying in church for us to do something about the global warming: "Please, humanity, don't screw this one up," as he feels uneasy with wiping us out, in the biblical sense.

But, I think, praying should mean that whoever is doing has no control, so the god should not be omnipotent for whatever reason and should feel powerless to influence the humanity. For example, he can perform miracles including earth destruction, but has no clue how to get us eradicate poverty of our own free will.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking a powerful being praying a less powerful being is a nonsense. It may be nice from the artistic perspective of a novel, but less meaningful under philosophic perspective.

There are two flavours for your question: is this god one of a monotheistic religion, or is it one among many in a polytheistic system?

**Monotheistic religion**

All monotheistic religion postulate that their god is the only, the very, the true. As corollary, this god is also omnipotent and omniscient. As a consequence of being omnipotent, he doesn't have to rely on an higher entity to have something done. So this god has nobody to pray.

**Polytheistic religion**

This one is easier: among gods there are various powers, some are more powerful, some are less. There are also *ubergods* which cannot be influenced at all (like Fate in Greek mithology). Therefore any minor god can pray a major god to achieve his/her favours, or even a major god has to yield to some other major god in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends of your perception of God :

**Wiki POV**

"The concept of God, includes the attributes of omniscience (infinite knowledge), omnipotence (unlimited power), omnipresence (present everywhere), divine simplicity, and as having an eternal and necessary existence. ...as being omnibenevolent (perfectly good) and all loving."

If this is your God (Monotheism), then he will not pray to anyone (as being perfect), but he will pray for all (as being all loving)

**Question POV**

If you can see God pray, he is either part of a cast of Gods or a God whose decision aren't perfect : he is a sentient being who can make choice and need to pray to a superior being. Said superior being can be a more powerful God (Like one of the primary Gods of a Polytheistic religion) or universal entities (like death/fate if it affects said God) or the Universe/environment in which he is living himself.
Lots of fiction actually invents a system where some Gods fight each other and make mistakes.

**Other POV**

If your God pray to (his?) people, it could also mean that, while he is omnipotent and omnipresent, he has the same opinion than the people having faith in him : He exists thanks to the people actions (prayer/faith) so he thanks them by praying to them.

**Conclusion**

God should pray to whom he believes is more powerful than him/her/it or has unfathomable impact on him. But if God is perfect he cannot pray to anything.

(As an atheist I am surprise I could reflect on the subject so thanks for the question OP)

Answer (score 0):

It may be god from your point of view. But is he/she "god" from his/her point of view?

You can pray back to people as in Foundation (Asimov) very advanced nation take over another world with religion. So less advanced would pray for them. But even that advanced people could pray for that second world, because they need them. But in different way, because less advanced people doesn't really need religion. On the other hand if you have only technology and nothing else - you need to trade with others.
Or gods can pray to "bigger" gods as In Stargate - People prayed for goa'ulds, but goa'ulds could pray for "higher beings" - because they knew they were unimaginably more powerful. (But it was selfish as Anubis did)
For example you are god (technically) to your dog/child. Can you pray for your dog? Can you pray for your child?